# calling external js file from html template

Tags: javascript, php, smarty

i'm having a problem during the onclick button calling an external js file, i'm getting error on the onclick function is not defined.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-nonfluid" style='width: auto;'>
        <tr>
            <td>Name: </td>
            <td><input type='text' name='ref_name' id='ref_name'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Description: </td>
            <td><input type='text' name='ref_desc'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2' align='right'><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' id="btn_save" onclick="saveMst();">Save</button></td> //this is the line onclick "saveMst()" is not defined when calling external js file.
            <input type='hidden' name='ref_type' value='1'>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

---

This is the scripts I defined in php:

```
$scripts = '<script type="text/javascript" src="js/references.js"></script>';

$smarty->assign('script', $scripts);
```

---

Here are the references.js code

```
function saveMst(){
sessionExpired();
if(mstValidate()==true){
    var url= "ref_deparment.php?do=save&save=mst&ref_name="+encodeURIComponent(ref_name)+
             "&ref_desc="+encodeURIComponent(ref_desc);
    alert (url);return false;
    topMsgDisplay('Saving... Please wait...');
    var myAjax = new Ajax.Request(url, { method: 'get', onComplete: function(oR){
        hideOverlay();  
        r = oR.responseText.split('||');
        //alert (oR.responseText);
        if(r[0]==1) {   
            $('btn_save').style.display = 'none';   
            alert('Record had been save sucessfully!');
            getEdit(r[1]);
        }
        else alert(r[1]);
    } });       
}
}

function mstValidate(){
﻿borderpass = '1px solid #ccc';
borderfail = '1px solid #f00';  

shortdesc = $('ref_name').value;
longdesc = $('ref_desc').value;

err_msg = 'You\'ve encounter the below error:\n';
pass=true;

if(shortdesc.length==0){
    pass=false;
    err_msg += '* Name field is left empty.\n';
    $('ref_name').style.border = borderfail;
}else {
    $('ref_name').style.border = borderpass;
}

if(longdesc.length==0){
    pass=false;
    err_msg += '* Description field is left empty.\n';
    $('ref_desc').style.border = borderfail;
}else {
    $('ref_desc').style.border = borderpass;
}

if(pass==false){
    alert(err_msg);
    return false;
}else return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you put a console.log('function works'); in your saveMst()?

Comment: is this the log you means?
ReferenceError: saveMst is not defined[Learn More]  ref_department.php:1:1
 onclick http://localhost/AJ_VhcRental/ref_department.php:1:1

Comment: If you put a console.log in your js code, it will tell you that the js file is loaded and the function is being called

Comment: saveMst() is a function in js to validate an empty field before saving into database.

Comment: there nothing prompt out after I put in the console.log, the same error occurs.

Comment: it seem like can't call up my external js file.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the event handler from the inline html to your javascript file. You should put that in a block that executes when the DOM is loaded so that you can be sure all elements you are attaching handlers to, exist.

As you seem to be using jquery, that would look something like:

```
$(function(){
    // Document ready
    $('#btn_save').on('click', function() {
        saveMst();
    });
});
```

Comment: may I know where or which file should I put this script in?

Comment: @ynlim Somewhere in the javascript file.